Regex does not match SSN or CC when its part of sentence
Please help me with my REGEX. Currently, we have code that replaces words/patterns. If I type in only the SSN like 123-12-1234.  It will be replaced by ***********. However, if I type in "My SS# is 123-12-1234" it will not work since its part of a sentence. I am not sure why my regex does not match this. Here it is:
^(?!(000|666|9))\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0000)\d{4}$^(?!(000|666|9))\d{3},(?!00)\d{2},(?!0000)\d{4}$

I tried using other regex such as : /\b\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\b/g but this does not work as well.
expected behavior is to match any pattern even if its in a sentence or paragraph.

Using ^ and $ will lock your expression to the start and end of string, respectively.  So your regular expression will only match when the whole string matches the expression.  In order to make it match portions of your string you need to remove those characters from your regular expression.
Something like the following will now parse it.
"jfjk dj fjdkf dj343-22-8031".match(/(?!(000|666|9))\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0000)\d{4}|(?!(000|666|9))\d{3},(?!00)\d{2},(?!0000)\d{4}/g)

You could state that it must be on word boundaries like so:
"jfjk dj fjdkf dj 343-22-8031".match(/\b(?!(000|666|9))\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0000)\d{4}\b|\b(?!(000|666|9))\d{3},(?!00)\d{2},(?!0000)\d{4}\b/g) // matches 343-22-8031

"jfjk dj fjdkf 1111343-22-8031".match(/\b(?!(000|666|9))\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0000)\d{4}\b|\b(?!(000|666|9))\d{3},(?!00)\d{2},(?!0000)\d{4}\b/g) // does not match

